# No method error occurs in rails while creating a new text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add a text field via form and setting the name as code.

My form calls a action verify in users controller. But when I run it

shows no method error code. I am new to rails can anyone help. I need to pass code as a params. I already created a user sign up and signin page.

```
<%= form_for(@user, :action => 'verify') do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :code %>
  <%= f.text_field :code  %>
<%= f.submit "Verify", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
```

// a action in usercontroller

```
def verify
end
```

Comment: You don't seem to set `@user` instance variable in your controller, which is required by your view.

Comment: I already set it when I created a new user i.e during signup

Comment: It doesn't matter, instance variables aren't magically 'moved' between requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user model probably does not have a `code` field. So the application is giving an error. If you just want to send `code`, use `form_tag` instead of `form_for`.

```
<%= form_tag verify_action_path do %>
  <%= label_tag :code %>
  <%= text_field_tag :code %>
  <%= submit_tag "Verify", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what is verify_action_path here?

Comment: View helper that points to verify action in the UserController. You can list paths with `rails routes` command. I wrote it as an example, you should write the correct path.

Comment: Thanks @demir it worked. Another thing is how can I access code in my verify action. Adding params besides code doesnt work.

Comment: @MrMoviesTamil You can access code in your action with: `params[:code]`